# No data found message inside h:dataTable or rich:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

How do i display a 'No Data Found' message inside a h:dataTable or a rich:dataTable. The header of the table should show the fields say Name, Roll Number and Class; The UI should show the header and a no data found message in the data section of the h:dataTable

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible with `h:dataTable` or `rich:dataTable`. The [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) [`p:dataTable`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHome.jsf) has an `emptyMessage` attribute which does exactly that.

Your best bet is to put a message below the table which is rendered when the table is empty. You could use CSS to give it the same style as the table so that it look like part of the table.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}">
    ...
</h:dataTable>
<h:outputText value="Table is empty" rendered="#{empty bean.list}">
```

Comment: If you remove the rendered attribute for datatable, the output will be the same as he expects!!!!!

Comment: For the benefit of somebody finding this later on: RF-3.3 `rich:extendedDataTable` has a `noDataLabel` and in RF-4.x this attribute can be used on `rich:dataTable`, too.

Answer (score 4):

Just a suggestion to make it easier to make the empty-message a part of the table, if you are not using the table footer anyway:

```
 ...
 </h:column>
 <f:facet name="footer">
    <h:outputText value="Table is empty" styleClass="someStyleClass" rendered="#{empty bean.list}" />
 </f:facet> 
 </h:datatable>
```

Some styling might be necessary anyway, but in my opinion it looks better in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

> Completely Possible.

```js
function myFunc(){
  $('#bodyForm\\:assetTrackingTravellingTable').grDataTable({
  sDom : 'zrtp'
 });
  
  }
```

```html
   
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/member/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/member/assets/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

<rich:dataTable id="assetTrackingTravellingTable" ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="var">
    <f:facet name="noData">
        No data message
    </f:facet>
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Field A"/></f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{var.fieldA}"/>
    </rich:column>
    ...
</rich:dataTable>
```